# visual svn , tortorise svn supported bug tracker

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, bug-tracking, bug-tracker

we are working on software development.
Currently we are using Visual SVN server(Free Version). and Tortoise SVN Client.
Currently we are excel sheets to report bugs.
we are thinking about switching to any bug tracking software.

My question is.
which is best bug tracking software which we can use with Visual SVN and Tortoise SVN Client.
I searched for trac but visual svn is closed support for that.
please help me out for finding best solution for our problem.
and  if u can then please provide some link how to integrate and use that software with Visual SVN server and Tortoise SVN Client.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: > Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Trac works with VisualSVN Server without any problems. Generally speaking, any bug tracker that supports Subversion should work well with VisualSVN Server and its repositories.

It is recommended to host Trac on a standalone server or on another Apache HTTP Server instance. Check these Trac docs that should help you:

- http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracOnWindows
- http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion.

VisualSVN Team does not recommend hosting Trac on the same Apache HTTP Server instance that is packaged with VisualSVN Server. However, it should be technically possible with help of `mod_wsgi` module (packaged with the server beginning with version 3.3.0) and Python 2.7 bindings (packaged with the server beginning with version 3.2.0).

Both `mod_wsgi` module and Python 2.7 bindings were specially packaged with VisualSVN Server to help you install Trac or any other tools requiring them, so everything needed for installing and configuring Trac is ready. It is possible to run Trac on top of `mod_wsgi` and the following instruction should help http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracModWSGI

**PS:** Some time ago VisualSVN Team provided a plug-in that helped to install Trac in a couple of easy steps. The plug-in was never officially released or supported and it is not available anymore.